# why subscribe method returns Subscriber instead of value in response

Tags: node.js, angular, response, subscriber

In my application User configuration are retrieved based config id which is available in node server .

```
  exports.getConfig() =(req,res) => {
 return res.status(200).send(id) -> where id is been read from configuration file 
}
```

In service i have get call that reads property in config file .

```
      getUserConfig():any {
        this.http.get('/config/user' , {responseType:'text'}).subscribe(data => {
       //console.log(data) ----- prints undefined 
        data
        )
        }
```

In ts i am storing the user configuration in a variable as follows

```
let userConfigValue = this.configService.getUserConfig();
//console.log(userConfigValue) --- prints subscriber object
```

I expected userConfigValue to be "1200" that is the value from file . What am i doing wrong here . How to get the value inside my angular component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not how the RxJS Observable pattern works. Any statements that directly depend on the asynchronous data emitted by the observable (like your assignment to `userConfigValue`) must be inside the subscription.

In your case you'd need to return the observable from the call and subscribe where it's response is required.

```js
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

getUserConfig(): Observable<any> {    // <-- return `Observable`
  this.http.get('/config/user' , { responseType:'text' }).pipe(
    tap((value: any) => console.log(value))   // <-- use `tap` for side effects (like logging)
  );
}
```

```js
userConfigValue: any;

this.configService.getUserConfig().subscribe({
  next: (value: any) => {
    this.userConfigValue = value;
    // other statements that depend on `this.userConfigValue`
  },
  error: (error: any) => {
    // error handling
  }
});
```

---

#### Next issue: `undefined` from backend

This is probably unrelated to the frontend. Make sure the `id` variable is defined before returning it from the server

```js
exports.getConfig = (req, res) => {  // <-- parenthesis to `getConfig` isn't required
  console.log(id);  // <-- make sure here it isn't `undefined`
  return res.status(200).send(id);
}
```